# Creating a tile server - what am I missing?

Tags: openlayers, tile-server

I have created a tile server using the instructions from [here](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/).

After creating this, I clicked the link in the bottom to continue creating my tile server for use.
I chose a library, Openlayers, to create a interactive map. But with Openlayers I am not requesting any tile from the tileserver?

I guess I am missing the step to communicate with the tile server? How to I place tile requests at my tileserver? 
How to use the tileserver with Openlayers?

Comment: You request tiles from your server by configure openlayers to use a tile server as a source. OpenLayers is a library - you have to build your map application. Have you looked at the examples that come with openlayers? http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/examples/ has many, and you can see the source for each. Perhaps http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/examples/localized-openstreetmap.html might be a useful example for you.